# XGBoost - Difference between scale_pos_weight and class_weights

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, xgboost, sklearn-pandas

Let's suppose we have a highly imbalanced binary classification problem in place. 
Now, XGBoost provides us with 2 options to manage class imbalance during training. One is using the parameter **scale_pos_weight** while the other is using **weights** parameter of the DMatrix.

For eg - 
I can either use - **params = {'scale_pos_weight' : some value}**
Or I can give class weights while creating the DMatrix like -
xgb = xgb.DMatrix(features, target, **weight**)

Can somebody please explain me the difference between these 2 cases? And how does the scores differ in both the cases?

Answer (score 4):

## The Difference

As explained in [the (python) documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html), `scale_pos_weight` is a float (i.e. single value), which allows you to adjust the classification threshold.  I.e. to tune the model's tendency to predict positive or negative values across the entire dataset.

`DMatrix`'s `weight` argument requires an array-like object and is used to specify a "*Weight for each instance*".  This allows more control over how the classifier makes its predictions, as each weight is used to scale the loss function that is being optimised.

### An Example

To make this difference more concrete, imagine we are trying to predict the presence of cats in pictures under two scenarios.

#### Scenario One

In this scenario, our dataset consists of images either with a cat or with no animal at all.  The dataset is imbalanced, with most images having no animal.  Here we might use `scale_pos_weight` to increase the weighting of positive (with cats) images to deal with the imbalance.

In general, we tend to set `scale_pos_weight` proportionally to the imbalance.  For example, if 20% of the images contain a cat, we would set `scale_positive_weight` to `4`.  (Of course this hyperparameter should be set empirically, e.g. using cross-validation, but this is a sensible initial/default value.)

#### Scenario Two

In this scenario, our dataset is again imbalanced with similar proportions of cat vs 'no-cat' images.  However, this time it also includes some images with a dog.  Potentially, our classifier may tend to mistake dogs for cats, decreasing its performance, with a higher false positive rate.  In this instance, we may wish to specify per-sample weights using `DMatrix`'s `weight` argument.  In effect we would attempt to penalise dog-related false positives, which would not be possible with a single factor applied to the overall classification threshold.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out your time and writing such an amazing answer. I still have a lot of doubts in my mind. I want to understand what exactly is the impact on the results of using these. Let's say I have a highly skewed problem and I decide to give a scale_pos_weight value of 5.0 to balance the positives. I am not using the DMatrix's weight parameter in this case. Let's say the model will get a score of 0.70 on the test set. In second case, I don't give a scale_pos_weight parameter, rather I give the array of weights in the weight parameter somewhat like [1, 5.0, 1, 5.0...]

Comment: Here as told above the 5.0 in the array corresponds to the positive samples in our data. Do you still expect the model to give out a score of 0.70 on test data? If yes, then how? Because I get different results.

Comment: @VatsalGupta that's a good question.  I tested this myself and don't get the same score.  My very simplistic expectation is that `scale_pos_weight` acts in a manner more akin to shifting the classification boundary whereas `DMatrix weight`s alter the shape of the boundary.  My understanding is that `DMatrix weight`s are multiplied with the gradient and hessians of the objective (loss) function, which directly impacts the construction of the trees.  `scale_pos_weight` is supplied as part of the `sklearn` wrapper and I'm unsure as to how it is applied, it may only be applied to leaf nodes.